Google Sheets/Apps Scripts to open to todays current date if dates are in columns
Having trouble finding a function that works for Google Sheets in Apps Scripts to open to todays current date.
All the formulas I find are for when the dates are in the first row but, my dates are in columns starting at B7:AE7. Your help would be much appreciated.

Welcome to StackOverFlow! Please take this opportunity to take the tour and learn how to ask, format the code, create a minimal reproducible example, etc.

You have a row of dates and you want to move the cursor to the current date when the spreadsheet is opened.
Consider this answer:

onOpen()

a Simple trigger that will run the function when the spreadsheet is opened


var dates = dateRange.getDisplayValues().flat()

Get the dates as displayed; these will be strings
flat will convert the 2D array to a 1D array for simplicity


var formattedToday = Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT+10", 'dd/MM/yyyy').toString()

format todays date and convert it to a string.


var result =dates.indexOf(formattedToday);

uses indexOf to find a match between today's date and the dates in the spreadsheet range.


if (result == -1){

if indexOf returns a value -1, then no match is found; the OP should include some code that caters for this contingency.


var targetRange = sheet.getRange(startRow,startColumn+result)

describes that cell to be made active.
note how the value of result is part of the cell Range.


targetRange.activateAsCurrentCell()

when a match is found, the target range is defined, and is set as the Current cell.




function onOpen() {
 gotoTodaysDate()
}

function gotoTodaysDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  var startRow = 7
  var startColumn = 2
  var endColumn = 31
  var dateRange = sheet.getRange(startRow,startColumn,1,endColumn-startColumn+1)
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the data range = "+dateRange.getA1Notation())
  // get the dates as string and flatten to a 1D array
  var dates = dateRange.getDisplayValues().flat()
  //Logger.log(dates) // DEBUG

  // get Todays date and format it as a string
  var today = new Date()
  //Logger.log(today) // DEBUG
  var formattedToday = Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT+10", 'dd/MM/yyyy').toString()
  //Logger.log(formattedToday) // DEBUG
  
  // use indexOf to find a match for today's date in the dates
  var result =dates.indexOf(formattedToday);
  //Logger.log(result) // DEBUG

  // if result = -1, then can't find date.
  if (result == -1){
    // date can't be found
    // OP to write any relevant code
    return
  }
  // otherwise, result = index value of the matched date
  // get the target cell and make it active
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(startRow,startColumn+result)
  targetRange.activateAsCurrentCell()

}


SAMPLE - before

SAMPLE - after


Sorry I tried that, making sure to change the sheet name, and that did not work. I appreciate the attempt though. Any other input or variations I should try?

You could have tried uncommenting the Logger statements and trouble-shooting, BUT... Substitute this line: var formattedToday = Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT-8", 'MM/d/yyyy').toString(). The difference is that your "day" value on sheet="November2024" is single digits from 1st-9th then double digits thereafter. My sample data used double digits for every date. So, we change the "day" element from "dd" to "d" and it should work.
